# Error occuring on Succesfull firebase authentication in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm currently trying to authenticate a user in firebase authentication in flutter. When I try to login from the username and password which is given in the database, I'm getting the following error and my app is crashing.

```
I/OpenGLRenderer(13205): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer(13205): Swap behavior 2
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(13205): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@8f2803a
W/DynamiteModule(13205): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth(13205): [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
I/FirebaseAuth(13205): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
E/JavaBinder(13205): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)

E/AndroidRuntime(13205):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:9)
E/AndroidRuntime(13205):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime(13205):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:735)
E/AndroidRuntime(13205): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/m20zero.admin-jiA3leeo3rmuvMlkECY0yw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/m20zero.admin-jiA3leeo3rmuvMlkECY0yw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/m20zero.admin-jiA3leeo3rmuvMlkECY0yw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(13205):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime(13205):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(13205):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(13205):    ... 16 more
I/Process (13205): Sending signal. PID: 13205 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Could you add your pubspec.yaml & app/gradle & global gradle?

Comment: version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: "0.3.0"
#  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.11
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.0+1
#  firebase_core: ^0.4.2+1
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
    uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: sorry sir i didnt know how to add the enitre file